# Azure Synapse Pipeline - Force Sharepoint Excel Data Refresh

Tags: excel, sharepoint, azure-synapse

I have a Synapse pipeline that pulls an .xlsx file from a Sharepoint folder into our datalake for later ingestion using a copy data activity. It was reported to me that the .xlsx file in Sharepoint is not having data refreshed from its external sources before it is being copied over. As a result, I need to manually go into the file and hit "Refresh All" before the pipeline kicks off. Within a synapse pipeline, is there a way to automate this task?

I believe that the file can be configured to auto-refresh when opened, but how can I go about opening the file through synapse or otherwise forcing a data refresh all?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint excel data from external sources cannot be refreshed using azure synapse pipeline or azure data factory. You can schedule to refresh it in SharePoint file itself.

- Click on the Properties and select Refresh every __ minutes. Enter the appropriate value in refresh every ---- minutes so that data get refreshed before azure synapse pipeline run.
  [image]

Reference: [Refreshing data in a workbook in SharePoint Server - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/refreshing-data-in-a-workbook-in-sharepoint-server-89560193-0c11-420b-b7d8-744766ccdc94)